# Adding row to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a datagridview which has 3 columns 1st and 2nd is textbox columns and 3rd one is link column. I try to add a new row using the command.

```
STEPS.Rows.Add(New String() {stepNo, "This is description for step " & stepNo},"link")
```

But for the first time when I try to execute the above line it shows `index was outside the bounds of the array`. This doesn't happen when I am trying to insert the second row.
Also this does not happen when I am having all the 3 columns as TextBoxs.

Please help me.

Comment: can you paste more info please your gridview code paste for see how you call each columns into your gridview.

Comment: See initially the STEPS DataGridView is empty. and above is the code that I use to add one row

Comment: geo i think row maybe be a datatable because rows.add is a method for datatable object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use step.rows.add method but steps is a gridview not a datatable. the datatable object contains a methods row.add that expect a datarow object, this example show add row into datatable , and link with a gridview.

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt.Columns.Add("field1")
    dt.Columns.Add("field2")

    Dim row1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    row1.Item("field1") = "Hello"
    row1.Item("field2") = "World"
    Dim row2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    row2.Item("field1") = "Hello2"
    row2.Item("field2") = "World2"
    dt.Rows.Add(row1)
    dt.Rows.Add(row2)
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
```